# C- While loop not working

Tags: c, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str1[1000];
    int i, letter, space = 0;
    char ch = str1[i];

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str1);
    printf("you enter %s\n", str1);

    while (i != strlen(str1)) {
        if (ch != ' ') {
            letter++;
        } else if (ch = ' ') {
            space++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d %d", letter, space);
}
```

My `while` loop isn't working and I can't seem to locate the problem. I am using the terminal in ubuntu and after printing the user string, I get a blank line. I have to use Ctrl-Z to stop the script.

Comment: `i` isn't initialized

Comment: `i` is not assigned to anything, perhaps try setting it to 0? `int i=0`

Comment: `char ch = str1[i];` this needs to be inside the loop. As now, `i` and `str` are uninitilaised.

Comment: This code just might be compiling somehow. Its poor in terms of basic fundamentals even.

Comment: `do.........while....................`

Comment: Try using a debugger... Also turn on compiler warnings to detect many uses of uninitialized variables.

Comment: `}else if (ch=' '){` is unnecessary, but it's also incorrect. You should be using `==` instead of `=` here.

Comment: `str1` isn't initialised as well.

Comment: What is this line `char ch = str1[i];` supposed to do?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding (and would have made many of the errors in the posted code obvious: 1) always, in comparisons, place the literal on the left. so the compiler catches any missing `=` 2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mistakes I see: using uninitialised variables - local variables do not get initialised automatically.

Another is you do not read a character from the string within the loop.

The third is the unecessary and syntactically incorrect `if (ch=' ')` which should have been `if (ch==' ')`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
    char str1[1000];
    int i = 0, letter = 0, space = 0;       // initialise all to 0;

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",str1);
    printf("you enter %s\n",str1);

    while (i!=strlen(str1)){
        char ch = str1[i];                  // move this inside the loop
        if (ch!= ' '){
            letter++;
        }else {                  // unnecessary - you already checked space
            space++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", letter, space);
}
```

Program session:

```
Enter a sentence: hallo my friend
you enter hallo my friend
13 2
```

Comment: just realized that was not my updated code. My mistake was thinking i could do int i,letter,space=0; thank you all

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize i to 0 at the beginning of the program.

```
int i,letter,space = 0;
```

the above line will only set space to 0 and not i.

Comment: `str1` needs be initialised as well.

Answer (score 0):

This shall work :

```
int i = 0;
int letter = 0;
int space = 0;
char ch = ' ';

printf("Enter a sentence: ");
scanf("%[^\n]s",str1);
printf("you enter %s\n",str1);

while (i!=strlen(str1)){
   ch = str1[i];
   if (ch!= ' '){
          letter++;
   } else {
         space++;
   }
   i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise `i` to `0` before entering the loop. Also `if (ch=' ')` should be `if (ch==' ')`. Next time, try to compile with warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra`).

Also, while probably not related to the issue here, using `strlen()` in a condition of a `while` statement can be a performance disaster if the string is too long. Furthermore, do note that the `scanf()` function may write beyond the end of the buffer if the input string is too long. For this specific case, I recommend getting the string using `getline()` (which dynamically allocates the necessary buffer).